# Where Do I find the PATH variable in ECLIPSE?

Tags: eclipse

I am using Eclipse and trying to build my Project with it but I keep getting this error:

```
Error: Program "gcc" not found in PATH
PATH=[D:\UserX\ArcticStudio-ppc-9.0.0-win32.win32.x86_64\\msys\bin]
```

I know that the path is not right . I want to edit this path. But I am not able to find its location to edit it. Could somebody please tell me where is it found? Thank you in avnce for your help.

Comment: `PATH` is a **Windows** environment variable. You need to define that in the Windows control panel.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name : I thought it needs to be edited within Eclipse. Thanks for your response